# Is it possible to change pseudo selectors such as hover using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am building a small game using Javascript and CSS. I have a series of elements that become highlighted when the player is active within them. I want to have a hover element where the cursor becomes a typical link pointer, but only for the elements adjacent to the currently active element. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. Is it possible to use jQuery to create a hover pseudo element just for the ids that I want for each adjacent element?

Comment: Sounds like something that could be done with CSS, had you given an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to accomplish this.  Your code will look something like this:

`$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`

You can get more information here:
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

selector will be a regular jQuery selector.  Use this to designate what we're watching for the hover on.

handlerIn and handlerOut are the things you want to occur when you enter and leave what you've selected.